# Preencher os inputs de um iframe

Tags: javascript, c#, iframe

Boa tarde.
Gostaria de saber se é possível preencher os inputs de iframe através de JavaScript.

```
<iframe src="http://frame.com" width="100%" height="800" id="frame"></iframe>
```

Sei que name do input do iframe e pensei nisso:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFrame() {
    $("input[name='txt_nm_requerente']").val("fernanda");
};
```

Mas não deu certo.

Comment: o `src` está no mesmo domínio da sua `pagina`? se não, você pode implementar uma troca de mensagens entre as paginas, mas terá de modificar ambas.

Comment: Não está. Meu sistema ainda local e o iframe é da prefeitura da minha cidade.

Answer (score 1):

Fernanda, infelizmente você vai cair da politica de segurança dos browsers, sendo que este não vai permitir que você modifique um documento em um domínio diferente ou acesse o mesmo usando AJAX.

Para você contornar isto, teria de modificar o um `header` na url da prefeitura, no caso o `allow-cross-origin`, mas acredito que você não tenha acesso a isto.

Você pode usar um Proxy para tentar contonar esta politica de segurança, como o `http://crossorigin.me/`, mas possivelmente não terá o resultado esperado.

Comment: Entendi, @TobyMosque, vou optar por algo mais simples então.

Answer (score 1):

utilizando uma versao do chrome anterior, ex: 71, você pode utilizar o "--disable-web-security" para abrir o chrome com a permissao para interagir entre frames de dominios diferentes, para contornar a proteção do navegador chamada cross origin, apos abrir o chrome dessa forma acessar a configuração chrome://flags e setar o "site isolation trial opt out"  para opt out e "strict site isolation" para disabled.  após, reiniciando o navegador funciona para isso e requisições ajax entre dominios diferentes em iframes ex: seu site puxando outro site num iframe, e seus scripts interagirem neste iframe por javascript, mas o chrome ira tentar atualizar automaticamente, então é bom desativar a atualização automatica do chrome. isso não é recomendado.
Em versoes do chrome mais atuais não funciona. só abaixo do 74